# Can Long datatype in java be used in looping statements?

Tags: java, long-integer

Why cant we manipulate long datatype in java effectively? I am newbie trying to improvise on java! I need to use Long datatype for the constraints provided but I have problems while trying to use it in the looping statements as it conflicts with the Integer variables in the looping statements. Do we have better ways of manipulating them? I am waiting for an enlightenment. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Can you be more specific to the issue your having? Also adding some code to illustrate where you're having issues would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use **long** instead of **Long**

this will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(long i=0; i<5;i++){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
```

EDIT (MORE INFORMATION):

Note that when you use **Long** you are instantiating a new object containing the **long** value.
The objects in java are handled through their pointer not their value, this can be useful when you need to manipulate an object inside a function  but you have to pay attention at the object's attribute.
In your case you can not use the **Long** object, using an object inside a for loop is like telling Java to increment the pointer but for security reasons Java avoid it.
If you need to use the **Long** object in the loop I suggest you to use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long i=(long) 0;
        while(true){
            if(i==5)
                break;
            System.out.println("Hello");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes `Long`is a class type that wraps `long`, but it is immutable and automatically "boxed" and "unboxed" when needed. It merely doesn't *promote* like the primitive types. `for ( Long i = (long)0; i<5; i++ )` works fine, and so does `for ( Long i = 0L; i<5; i++  )`.